# Android dynamic auto-complete - minor fix - code attached

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a dynamic autocomplete widget in android. I am done with the major functionalities and the autocompletion implemented is for youtube video search.

When I start typing a letter or two, the auto-completion is not working. But when I type three letters or more it works prfect. It also works when I type two letters and hit a backspace. I do not know what is wrong with the code.

I have uploaded the code [here](http://www.4shared.com/file/4xuD7jXy/YoutubeAutoComplete.html)

Experts, kindly guide me. I would be obliged if you can point out where I have gone wrong with the code.

Any help in this regard is well appreciated.

Looking forward,
Regards,
Rony

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class YoutubeAutoComplete extends Activity {
Youtube yt = new Youtube();
CustomAutoComplete myAutoComplete;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private JSONArray js;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myAutoComplete = (CustomAutoComplete) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    myAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    js = yt.GetSuggestions(s.toString()).getJSONArray(1);
                    messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};

private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        adapter.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++) {
            try {
                adapter.add(js.getJSONArray(i).getString(0));
                System.out.println(js.getJSONArray(i).getString(0));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

}
```

Comment: It is more useful if you provide the relevant snippet of code directly in the question.  People don't want to go downloading arbitrary files in orde to help you.

Comment: Hi, I have edited and added source code.

Comment: Hello, now that the required source code is here. Can someone have a look at it and find out what gives the issues I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at completionThreshold AKA the number of characters the user must type before getting completion suggestions.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:completionThreshold